# Error In classes C++

Tags: c++, class

I have to make a program to display the weather in Sheffield since 1930.

I have to use sheffield.data for the record.

I have 3 files. Data.cpp, Data.hpp and analyze.cpp

analyze.cpp:

```
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "data.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 MonthData data();

  vector<MonthData> vectorData;
  ifstream file ("sheffield.data");
  string line;
  int l_num = 0;

  if (file.is_open()) {
    while (getline(file, line))
      if (l_num < 4) {
        l_num += 1;
      }
      else {
        file >> data;
        vectorData.push_back(data);  
      }  

      float MinimumDeg = vectorData[0].getMinimum();
      int year = vectorData[0].getYear();
      for ( size_t a = 0; a < vectorData.size(); a++)
      {
        MinimumDeg = vectorData[a].getMinimum();
        year = vectorData[a].getYear();
      }

      cout << "Lowest year and month lowest rainfall: '\n'" << "Min Temp;" << MinimumDeg << "C '\n'" << "Year" << year << endl;


      return 0;

}  

}
```

:

data.cpp

```
#include "data.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

istream& operator >> (istream& in, MonthData& data)
{
  in >> data.year >> data.year >> data.temp_maximum >> data.temp_minimum >> data.air_frost >> data.rain >> data.sun;

  return in;
}
```

data.hpp:

```
#ifndef DATA_HPP
#define DATA_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

class MonthData
{
  friend istream& operator >> (istream&, MonthData&);

  public:
        //overload constructor
    MonthData(double, int, double, double, int, double, double);

        //Accessor functions
    double getYear() const    { return year; }                //returns the year
    int getMonth() const      { return month; }               //returns the month
    double getMaximum() const { return temp_maximum; }        //returns maximum temperature
    double getMinimum() const { return temp_minimum; }        //returns minimum temperature
    int getFrost() const      { return air_frost; }           //returns air frost
    double getRain() const    { return rain; }                //returns rainfall
    double getSun() const     { return sun; }                 //returns no of hours of sunshine

  private:
    double year;
    double month;
    double temp_maximum;
    double temp_minimum;
    int air_frost;
    double rain;
    double sun;
};
#endif
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
[sc14da@cslin035 cw]$ g++ data.cpp data.hpp analyze.cpp -o analyze
analyze.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
analyze.cpp:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘MonthData::MonthData()’
data.hpp:17: note: candidates are: MonthData::MonthData(double, int, double, double, int, double, double)
data.hpp:12: note:                 MonthData::MonthData(const MonthData&)
```

Comment: You never defined a default or copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not provide any constructor in your class, the compiler will automatically create one for you.
In your class, you have specified a particular constructor:

```
MonthData(double, int, double, double, int, double, double);
```

As soon as you provide any constructor, the compiler will not create a default constructor (i.e. one that takes no parameters).

You are calling

```
MonthData data();
```

You are passing no parameters here but you have no constructor that takes no parameters.
You probably meant to call

```
MonthData data(with 7 parameters);
```

Alternatively, add the following to your MonthData class body:

```
MonthData();
```

Then in your data.cpp, need to provide the code for what this constructor should do, i.e.

```
MonthData::MonthData()
{
   //Initialise as required - but better to use a member initialization list
}
```

It would be better to use a member initialization list for your 7 member variables.
For example:

```
MonthData::MonthData()
 : year(2014), month(2), temp_maximum(15.4), temp_minimum(2.1), air_frost(5), rain(5.6), sun(7.6)    //Use desired default values
{}
```

This simple constructor code could instead be put directly in the class body in the header file:

```
class MonthData
{
  public:
    //overload constructor
    MonthData(double y, int m, double max, double min, int fr, double r, double s)
: year(y), month(m), temp_maximum(max), temp_minimum(min), air_frost(fr), rain(r), sun(s) {};

    //default constructor
    MonthData()
: year(2014), month(2), temp_maximum(15.4), temp_minimum(2.1), air_frost(5), rain(5.6), sun(7.6) {};

    etc
};
```

In addition - review your variable types. Should year really be a double? Also you have month declared as a double but your accessor returns an int.

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising as **you haven't included a default constructor**. Or, more specifically, a constructor that matches this line:

```
MonthData data();
```

Solution: add a default constructor in your base `MonthData` class (data.hpp).

Comment: I am new to C++ and classes in it can you describe how it is done?

Comment: All text books should show how to make a default constructor.  Have you read yours lately?